# Global variable hidden in actionperformed

Tags: java, variables, methods, global, hidden

I am including a snipped of my code. The variable fnh was declared with class scope ( right after the class definition ). Yet, I can´t et it to print with the last statement. It does print the value of the variable if placed inside the actionPerformed method, but not outside it. What could possibly be the problem? Any prompt suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Lamp  {
   int fnh;
   Lamp()  {
     // More code here

  String[] numberOfRunners = { "8", "9", "10", "11", "12",
                                "13", "14", "15", "16", "17",
                                "18", "19", "20", "21", "22" };

   runners = new JComboBox( numberOfRunners );
   runners.setMaximumRowCount(5);        
   runners.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {
           String  runnersNumber = ( String )runners.getSelectedItem();
           fnh = Integer.parseInt( runnersNumber );           
           reducedFNH = reduce( fnh );
       }}
   );     
   middle.add( runners );
   System.out.println( fnh );

    // More code here

}
```

// More code

} end of class

Answer (score 0):

Missing `}` at the end.

Easiest answer I ever gave :-D

Comment: Missing bracket would give "unexpected EOF while parsing", but the OP didn´t say any parsing error occured.

Comment: Wee, that part I figured... As I said, that´s just a snippet of the code.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the value of fnh is still null at the time you want to print it. The first time it gets a value is in the actionperfomed method.

Comment: Java will initialize int variables to zero by default. Not null.

Comment: AS you see, I am a newbiw. How do I get to use that value in other parts of the code? I thought that declaring it with class scope would be enough....

Comment: The variable is usable in the rest of the code. But fnh=0 until the actionperformed method is called the first time.

Comment: Peter, thank you so very much for your attention in this matter. This project I am working on is very important, and most of its functionality is working just fine. But I don´t seem to be able to overcome this issue ( and perhaps nor explain myself clearly on here... ) If you don´t mind sharing your email address with me, I can send you a bigger portion of the code and explain myseld a little better.. asgaard777@gmail.com Marcos –

Comment: I am going to work on the problem a little more. Based on your explanation above I think I´ll be able to see what I am doing wrong. If not, I´ll get back to you. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You register your actionListener, and after that you output `fnh`. 
It has not changed yet, since no action was performed, so your listener was not called.

Maybe it's easier to understand like this:

```
public class Lamp  {
   int fnh;
   ...

   private ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {
          // This is only called, when user performs an action on runners
          String  runnersNumber = ( String )runners.getSelectedItem();
          fnh = Integer.parseInt( runnersNumber );
      }};

    public Lamp()  {
        ...
        runners = new JComboBox(numberOfRunners);
        runners.addActionListener(actionListener);
        System.out.println( fnh );
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that suggestion. But why can´t I use anonymous inner class to handle that event?

Comment: Peter, thank you so very much for your attention in this matter. This project I am working on is very important, and most of its functionality is working just fine. But I don´t seem to be able to overcome this issue ( and perhaps nor explain myself clearly on here... ) If you don´t mind sharing your email address with me, I can send you a bigger portion of the code and explain myseld a little better.. asgaard777@gmail.com Marcos

Comment: Peter, I figured the problem! My project is done. Thank you so very much! You are indeed a great asset to this community.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :) You can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the best answer if your problem is solved, and you can also [vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote) for all helpful answers.